# Change translation for individual product or category

Tags: localisation, language, magento-1.7

I am working on a magento store setup which sells both Products and Class Subscription.

Products detail page i would like to show description title as **Product Description** but when it is a Class Subscription (these are product in separate Category) i need it to be **Class Details**

As i need it for a particular product, i cannot change it in particulate. It there any option to override translation for particular product or category. May be through layout xml update.
Or is there any other standard approach to do this in magento.

Answer (score 2):

1. No there is not. I think the easiest part ist to just check, what attribute/attribute set/product_type (however you can differ the two things) and then echo the one or the other.
2. You can add a template to echo the one or the other, add a layout file and change the template based on the attribute set, product type, whatever. [Layout handle, based on attribute set is described here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6176/layout-handle-from-attribute-set)
3. Every product offers a custom layout update, but I think this is a lot of work, if you have more than X products and if you will have more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Create another group for your 'Class Subscription' from 'Products' and then Use if in your phtml file

for example :
`if group=default` then `echo $this->__('Product Description')` and `if group=class` then `echo $this->__('Class Details')`